# In php we have to loop or any special thing to do this?

Tags: php

```
php> $a = array("a"=>1,"b"=>0,"c"=>1,"d"=>1,"e"=>0);

php> $b = array();

php> foreach ($a as $k =>$v){
 ...   if($v != 0){
 ...     $b["$k"] = $v;
 ...   }
 ... }

php> print_r($b);
Array
(
    [a] => 1
    [c] => 1
    [d] => 1
)

php>
```

Anyways to do it not using loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) is what you need.

```
function notZero($var)
{
    // returns whether the input integer is not zero
    return $var != 0;
}

$a = array("a"=>1,"b"=>0,"c"=>1,"d"=>1,"e"=>0);

print_r(array_filter($a, "notZero"));

//Prints what you need
Array
(
    [a] => 1
    [c] => 1
    [d] => 1
)
```

Comment: The callback is superfluous in this case.

Answer (score 2):

```
$a = array("a" => 1, "b" => 0, "c" => 1, "d" => 1, "e" => 0);
$b = array_filter($a);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_map` or `array_filter` but I suggest you to stay with your code.

Comment: I belive both can do that, anyway added filter too

Answer (score 1):

With PHP 5.3 you could use [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter) in combination with a closure:

```
$nonZeroes = array_filter($yourArray, function ($value) {
    return $value;
});
```